# How do I connect my AAL06 dimmer for single pole?

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I just purchased a few of these AAL06 dimmers.

The instructions manual says @easy: connect black to black, green to green, and anything else to white, my situation is very different... here is the [wiring diagram](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/17/17f20bd0-6ba9-472d-bdb2-f311906f781e.pdf).

Note that in picture 1, the lower black cable has power and not the top one, when lights are off.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me which cable to wire to where ? This is just for single pole.

Thank you so much in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 3):

### This really is as easy as the instructions make it out to be

First, turn the breaker off.  You'll want to do this one wire at a time though, so don't undo the switch completely straight away.

The bottom black wire is your always-hot coming in, and gets nutted to the black wire on the dimmer after it's removed from the switch.  The top black wire is the switched hot going to the lamp, and gets nutted to to the red wire on the dimmer after it has its turn at floating free.  The yellow (interconnect) and white (neutral) wires on the dimmer get nutted in with the existing neutral wires (as specified by the instructions for a single pole installation), and the green ground wire on the dimmer gets nutted in with the existing bare wires.

Button it all up, turn the breaker on, and enjoy your new dimmer!